# Adding a save system to my game

Tags: ruby, save, yaml

I have been working a Text Adventure in Ruby called Conquest, and I'm very happy with where it's going, but I'd like to add the ability to save your game soon. I used to just do stuff like this with YAML, but I'd imagine theres a better way.

This game is also a bit more complicated than others that I've made, so I want a very easy way to manage the save system.

I thought about doing something like this with YAML for every instance of my custom classes in my game:

```
--- !ruby/object:Player
items: ...
```

But I figured that is probably a bad way to go about it. I'll show you some of my files and I'd love to know what you think is the best way to go about this. And remember it's in progress so some things like the quests don't fully work but you'll get the point.

lib/player.rb:

```
class Player

    attr_accessor :items

    def initialize
        @items = {}
        @quests = QuestList.quests
    end

    def pickup(key, item)
        @items[key.to_sym] = item
        if key == "scroll"
            @quests[:mordor].start
        end
    end

    def inventory
        @items.values.each { |item|
            a_or_an = %w[a e i o u].include?(item.name[0]) \
                ? "an " : "a " 
            a_or_an = "" if item.name[-1] == "s"
            puts "#{a_or_an}#{item.name.downcase}"
        }
    end

end
```

lib/item.rb:

```
class Item

    attr_reader :name, :description, :hidden, :can_pickup

    def initialize(name, description, options = {})
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @options = options
        @hidden = options[:hidden] || false
        @can_pickup = options[:hidden] || true
        add_info
    end

    def add_info
    end

end

class Prop < Item
    def add_info
        @hidden = true
        @can_pickup = false
    end
end

# sends you to a new room, usally something that
# has more functionality than just a room
class Transporter < Prop

    attr_accessor :goto

    def add_info
        @hidden = true
        @can_pickup = false
        @goto = options[:goto]
    end
end

# SUBCLASSES BELOW: (only subclass when you have a good reason)

# can be eaten,
# use item.is_a? Food
class Food < Item
end

class Tree < Prop

    def climb
        if @options[:can_climb]
            puts @description
        else
            puts "You start climbing the tree, but you don't get far before you fall down."
        end
    end
end
```

lib/quest_list.rb (this'll probably be replaced by the saving system):

```
module QuestList

    QUESTS = {
        # this need a better name ⬇️ 
        main:   Quest.new("The main mission", []),
        mordor: Quest.new("Onward to Mordor", [])
    }

    def self.quests
        QUESTS
    end

end
```

lib/room_list.rb (this'll probably be replaced by the saving system as well):

```
module RoomList

    ROOMS = {
        castle_main:
            Room.new("Main room", "This is the main room of the castle. It needs a better description\nand name. Theres a hallway south.", 
                paths: { s: :hallway}
                ),
        hallway:
            Room.new("Hallway", "This castle has a long hallway. There is a door to the west and\na large room north.",
                paths: { n: :castle_main, s: :castle, w: :dinning_hall }
                ),
            dinning_hall:
                Room.new("Dinning hall", "The dinning hall. There is a door to the east.",
                    paths: { e: :hallway }
                    ),
        castle:
            Room.new("Castle", "You are in the castle. There's a long hallway to the north, and\nthe courtyard is to the south.",
                paths: { n: :hallway, s: :courtyard }
                ),
        courtyard:
            Room.new("Castle courtyard", "You are at the castle courtyard. There's a nice fountain in the center.\nThe castle entrance is north. There is a forest south.",
                paths: { n: :castle, s: :forest },
                items: {
                    # this peach is useless, it'll confuse people 
                    # a peach: 
                    peach: Food.new("Peach", "A delicious peach")
                    }),
        forest:
            Room.new("Large forest", "This forest is very dense. There is a nice courtyard north.\nThe forest continues west and south.",
                paths: { n: :courtyard, s: :forest_1, w: :forest__1 }
                ),
    forest__1:
        Room.new("Large forest", "This forest is very nice. You can go north, east and west into\nsome more forest.", 
            paths: { n: :forest__2, e: :forest, w: :sticks }
            ),
sticks:
    Room.new("Large forest", "This forest is getting boring, but hey, who knows what you'll find here!\nYou can go east.",
        paths: { e: :forest__1 },
        items: {
            sticks: Item.new("Sticks", "Just a couple of sticks. They like they are cedar wood.")
            }),
    forest__2:
        Room.new("Large forest",  "You are in a large forest. There looks like theres a grand building over\neast, but you can't quite get to it from here. You can go south.",
            paths: { s: :forest__1 }
            ),
        forest_1:
            Room.new("Large forest", "There is a large, magnificent tree east. The forest continues\nnorth and south.",
                paths: { n: :forest, e: :banyan_tree, s: :forest_2 }
                ),
            banyan_tree:
                # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banyan
                Room.new("Large banyan tree", "There is a large banyan tree, with many twists and roots going up the tree.\nYou can go west.",
                    paths: { w: :forest_1 },
                    items: {
                        tree: Tree.new("Banyan", "You climb up the top of the tree, and see lots of trees and a\ncastle somewhere around north. It looks like there is a small\nvillage some where south east. You climb back down.", { # 
                            can_climb: true
                            })}),
        forest_2:
            Room.new("Large forest", "Just some more forest. The forest continues north and south.",
                paths: { n: :forest_1, s: :forest_3 }
                ),
        forest_3:
            Room.new("Large forest", "Dang, how many trees are in this forest? You can go north, south, and west.",
                paths: { n: :forest_2, s: :forest_4, w: :more_trees }
                ),
    more_trees:
        Room.new("Large forest", "You can go east and west.",
            paths: { e: :forest_3, w: :more_trees_1 }
            ),
more_trees_1:
    Room.new("Large forest", "You can go east and south.", 
        paths: { e: :more_trees, s: :more_trees_2 }
        ),
more_trees_2:
    Room.new("Large forest", "You can go north and south.",
        paths: { n: :more_trees_1, s: :more_trees_3 }
        ),
more_trees_3:
    Room.new("Large forest", "You can go north and east",
        paths: { n: :more_trees_2, e: :path_to_village }
        ),
        path_to_village:
            Room.new("Large forest", "Its hard to see because of all these trees, but you think you see a small\nhut to the east. You can also go back west",
                paths: { e: :village, w: :more_trees_3 }
                ),
            village:
                # add an item or 2 here
                Room.new("Abandon village", "There are a bunch of huts here, some people must have lived here before.\nThere is some more forest down south. You can go back west into the forest.",
                    paths: { w: :path_to_village, s: :forest_by_village },
                    items: { 
                        pickaxe: Item.new("Pickaxe", "Be careful, it looks sharp.")
                        }),
            forest_by_village:
                Room.new("Large forest", "Geez more forest. The village is north, and there is a valley east",
                    paths: { n: :village, e: :valley }
                    ),
                valley:
                    Room.new("Valley", "It's a beautiful valley, with some giganic mountains east, with some\nsnow of the tops. There is a forest to the west",
                        paths: { e: :mountains, w: :forest_by_village }
                        ),
                    mountains:
                        Room.new("Mountains", "There are many tall mountains with snow on the tops. You can go back west.",
                            paths: { u: :mountain, w: :valley },
                            has_mountain: true
                            ),
                        mountain:
                            Room.new("Tall mountain", "This mountain is very steep. You can continue climbing or go back down",
                                paths: { d: :mountains, u: :mountain_1 },

                                # the scroll and Randy should be moved to mountain_3 once it exists
                                items: {
                                    scroll: Item.new("Scroll", "Its some kind of elvish... You can't read it.") },
                                people: {
                                    # Randy will read elvish in the future
                                    randy: Person.new("Randy", "He's just an elf",
                                        race: "Elf",
                                        talk: "I can read elvish. Go figure."
                                        )}),
                        mountain_1:
                            Room.new("Tall mountain", "Climbing this mountain is very tiring. You can continue climbing\nor go back down",
                                paths: { d: :mountain }
                                ),
        forest_4:
            Room.new("Large forest", "There is a lot of trees here. It's very shady in this area.\nThe forest continues north.", 
                paths: { n: :forest_3 }
                )
    }

    def self.room_list
        ROOMS
    end

end
```

lib/delegate.rb:

```
class Delegate

    attr_accessor :current_room

    def initialize
        @rooms = RoomList.room_list
        @player = Player.new
        @current_room = @rooms[:courtyard]
        @help = 0
    end

    def parse(input)
        directions = "up|down|north|east|south|west|u|d|n|e|s|w"
        # input will always be converted to lower case before getting here
        case input
        when /^(?<direction>(#{directions}))$/
            direction = $~[:direction]
            walk(direction)
        when /^(go|walk)( (?<direction>#{directions}|to mordor))?$/
            direction = $~[:direction]
            if direction
                walk(direction)
            else
                puts "#{input.capitalize} where?"
            end
        when /^(get|take|pickup|pick up)( (?<item>[a-z ]+))?$/
            item = $~[:item]
            if item
                pickup(item)
            else
                puts "Please supply an object to #{input}."
            end
        when /^look( (?<item>[a-z]+))?$/
            item = $~[:item]
            item.nil? ? look : inspect(item)
        when /^inspect( (?<item>[a-z]+))?$/
            item = $~[:item]
            if item
                inspect(item)
            else
                puts "Please supply an object to inspect."
            end
        when /^rub sticks( together)?$/
            rub_sticks
        when /^quests?$/
            # this is probably going to be a for statement.  You understand thos more than i do so have at it.
            # this should loop through the list of quests in quests.yml and return the ones that are true

            # correction: it should call .each, for statments are bad practice in ruby
        when /^(i|inv|inventory)$/
            inventory
        when /^climb( (?<tree_name>[a-z]+))?( tree)?$/
            # this regex needs to be cleaned up, just the tree part really
            # nvm, the whole regex sucks
             = $~[:tree_name]
            climb()
            # doesn't have to be a tree...
        when /^(help|h)$/
            @smart_aleck ||= ["Why?","No.","Stop asking plz.","seriously, shut up.","...","...","...","Ok, seriously.","Do u not understand the meaning of \"be quiet\"?","ug"].to_enum
            begin
                puts @smart_aleck.next
            rescue StopIteration
                @smart_aleck.rewind
                puts @smart_aleck.next
            end
        when /^(quit|exit)$/
            quit
        when /^\s?$/
        else
             = ["I don't speak jibberish.","Speak up. Ur not making any sense.","R u trying to confuse me? Cuz dats not gonna work","What the heck is that supposed to mean?"]
            puts .sample
        end
    end

    def walk(direction)
        if direction != "to mordor"
            if new_room = @rooms[@current_room[direction]]
                @current_room = new_room.enter
            else
                puts "You can't go that way."
            end
        else
            #TODO: add quest system.  We should have a main quest and other side quests like going to mordor.
            puts "One does not simply walk to Mordor... You need to find the eagles. They will take you to Mordor."
        end
    end

    def pickup(item)
        if _item = @current_room.items[item.to_sym]
            if _item.can_pickup
                _item = @current_room.remove_item(item)
                @player.pickup(item, _item)
            else
                puts "You can't pick that up."
            end
        else
            puts "That item isn't in here."
        end
    end

    def inventory
        @player.inventory
    end

    def look
        @current_room.look
    end

    def inspect(item)
        # this could be refactored
        if the_item = @player.items[item.to_sym]
            puts the_item.description
        elsif the_item = @current_room.items[item.to_sym]
            puts the_item.description
        else
            puts "This item is not here or your inventory."
        end
    end

    def rub_sticks
        if @player.items[:sticks]
            # do something involving fire
            puts "I need to implement this."
        end
    end

    def climb(thing_name)
        if  = @current_room.items[:tree]
            name = .name.downcase
            if thing_name.nil? || thing_name == "tree" || thing_name == name
                .climb
            else
                puts "You can't climb that."
            end

        # I don't like how this works :(
        elsif @current_room.options[:has_mountain]
            if ["up", "mountain", nil].include? thing_name
                walk("u")
            end
        else
            puts "You can't climb that."
        end
    end

    def quit
        exit
    end

end
```

lib/quest.rb:

```
class Quest

    attr_accessor :steps

    def initialize(name, steps, options = {})
        @name = name

        # steps (the argument) should be a hash like this:
        # [:found_ring, :melted_ring]
        @steps = steps.inject({}) { |hash, step| hash[step] = false; hash }
        # then @step will be this:
        # { found_ring: false, melted_ring: false }

        @started = false
        @options = options
    end

    def start
        @started = true
        puts "#{'Quest started!'.cyan} - #{name}"
    end

end
```

lib/room.rb:

```
class Room

    attr_reader :items, :options, :people

    def initialize(name, description, options = {})
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @paths = options[:paths] || {}
        @items = options[:items] || {}
        @people = options[:people] || {}
        @options = options
        @visited = false
    end

    def [](direction)
        @paths[direction.to_sym]
    end

    def enter
        puts @name.cyan
        unless @visited
            puts @description
            list_items
        end
        @visited = true # can't hurt to set it every time, right?
        self
    end

    def remove_item(item)
        @items.delete(item.to_sym)
    end

    def look
        puts @name.cyan
        puts @description
        list_items
    end

    def list_items
        visible_items = @items.values.select { |i| (!i.hidden) && i.can_pickup }
        unless visible_items.empty?

            puts "Items that are here:".magenta
            visible_items.map do |item|
                a_or_an = %w[a e i o u].include?(item.name[0]) \
                    ? "an " : "a "
                a_or_an = "" if item.name[-1] == "s"
                puts "#{a_or_an}#{item.name.downcase}"
            end
        end

        visible_people = @people.values.select { |i| (!i.hidden) && i.can_pickup }
        unless visible_people.empty?

            puts "People that are here:".magenta
            visible_people.map do |people|
                puts "#{people.name}"
            end
        end

    end

end
```

I know that `Delegate.current_room` should be a property of Player not Delegate if I'm gonna be saving it, I just haven't gotten around to fixing that.

So what do all of you think of saving this with YAML serialization? (the ugly `!ruby/object:Class` stuff)

I would really like to know of a better way to go about this, but I can't think of anything. I was thinking I could put the yaml or other save format in ~/.conquest_save

I'd love to here all your input, thanks! And the full project is on Github [here](https://github.com/INOVA-Technology/Conquest).

Comment: why not a db and a `player_gateway`?

Comment: You could throw an sqlite3 database in, since it's just a file. That would be the most elegant and readable way that comes to mind.

Comment: I thought about that, but I didn't know if you could or how to save ruby objects like my player class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Marshal.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Marshal.html

The two main methods to use will be these:

```
data = Marshal.dump(o)
obj = Marshal.load(data)
```

LPC MUDs traditionally use SQL, actually. I found that out when I had some error and got a matrix failure, then looking at the log and I saw SQL related errors to my big surprise.

I also tried my luck with a MUD and I actually said to myself that if it gets more complicated than yaml files then this is a way I won't go.

I think if your system actually will become more complicated, have you tried to abstract away and just use a wrapper over something like postgresql or mysql, like activerecord?

Comment: This says its part of Ruby core in 2.1.2, which I am using, but its saying `load such file -- marshal` I like this idea though, thanks!

Comment: I added this to my game, and it works great! Thanks!

Comment: I have a question about this, I recently had to stop using Marshal to save my game because it didn't update any values I changed in a later version. For example, each room has a `@paths` property which is a hash. So once Marshal saved a room, if I added a path to `@paths`, it wouldn't be there unless I restart the game and remove the old file that was saved. This is just one example, this happened with many other thing like the `@tasks` property of a quest and much more. Do you have an idea how to prevent this, and still use Marshal?